# Mandrill Track Open not working

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, tracking, mandrill

Currently I send my mail using PHPMailer using [Mandrill's instructions](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23737696-How-do-I-send-with-PHPMailer).

My email is sent successfully and goes into my gmail/hotmail inbox.

I clicked and open but had no idea why the chart on my Outbound Activity didn't show I had open/click the email. Is it needed to be wait few days only the data reflected on my graph?

I also checked my settings on Mandrill, I did track the open/click email on my settings.

[image]

Comment: Those instructions only cover the sending - you need to include their tracking image in your message content.

Comment: @Synchro I inspect the mail element and  have their tracking image tag inside the email,
`<img src="http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=30262953&amp;id=a5404c99ed4e43aca2af5b33b6fb7ea8" height="1" width="1">`

Comment: That looks ok, and it certainly delivers an image when you open it (you probably just got a hit from me opening it!). I suspect that their stats are not updating that quickly. Otherwise I'd contact their support rather than asking here.

Comment: I hardly find their contact in their website, so I posted at here and my point of view , am thinking of if people facing same problem as mine they can refer at here, stackoverflow. : \

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Opens and clicks are tracked when they happen, but the stats don't update in real-time. Mandrill queues the open or click event, processes it for the specific email, and then adds the open or click to the message index for your account. That typically happens within a few minutes, though can sometimes take longer, depending on other factors such as load on the system. We always prioritize sending over things like opens and clicks so that open and click tracking doesn't slow down delivery of messages.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.. You saved me from feeling that I am doing something wrong in configuration.
Secondly, What if user does not download the image that mandrill sends.. will we never be able to track open status? Is it anyway possible to force download that image?

Comment: Thanks to Kaitlin@Mandrill -- I'm having these same questions today, and the help here @Stack is useful.

Comment: @Win8_learner - no, it's not possible to force downloading of remote images. That's typically a security feature. You can try to incentivize people to do it (by adding relevant, useful, interesting images in your content, for example), but it can't be forced.